# Hour calculator from a single cell with two values

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a new rota. (I'm a team leader in a pub but I normally handle the tech issues).

I want to calculate the hours as a running total. The difficult bit is that the user enters hours in a single cell as follows.

1100 - 1600

I need to make Excel fit the user.

I want is to take the info from the cell, split it in two and then calculate the hours, adding them to a running total which is then put into a cell at the end of each person's week on the rota.

I've basic knowledge of Python. I've got about 3000 tabs open from Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Comment: Can you please post what you have attempted and the errors you are seeing so as to allow the community help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of changing text data to time data should be preceded. Then you just need to calculate the difference between the two and sum them up. You can use Split function and Timeserial function.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet 'set worksheet, set Ws = Sheets(1)
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) ' set data range
    End With
    
    vDB = rngDB 'get value from range to 2D array
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 3) 'make new 2D array
    For i = 1 To r
        vSplit = Split(vDB(i, 1), "-")
        
        s1 = Trim(vSplit(0)) '1100
        s2 = Trim(vSplit(1)) '1600
        
        vR(i, 1) = TimeSerial(Left(s1, 2), Right(s1, 2), 0) '11:00
        vR(i, 2) = TimeSerial(Left(s2, 2), Right(s2, 2), 0) '16:00
        vR(i, 3) = vR(i, 2) - vR(i, 1) '16:00 - 11:00
    Next i
    
    'Wirte  Result array vR to Sheet cell "c1"
    With Ws
        With .Range("c1").Resize(r, 3)
            .Value = vR
            .NumberFormatLocal = "hh:mm"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

### sheet image

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this code, after spending some time researching all the little intricacies involved I feel much better about my skills in Excel and have even managed to make the code a function that works across a range and tallies up the hour count total. 

Your help was immeasurable and I really appreciate it.

Thank you!